# Windows Drive Name After Z?

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, storage, storage-spaces

I was wondering what will be the drive name used after Z:?

I am planning to mount few virtual drives on my Windows machine and also have a plan to create few drives out of my existing 2TB HDD.

My question is what drive is chosen after Z: or will this not be allowed for me to create a device after Z:?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652545/windows-what-happens-if-i-finish-drive-letters-they-are-26

Comment: How to delete this question?

Comment: @Burgi, Please help me deleting this question

Comment: @manjesh23 There is no need to delete the question, it is not offensive, spam, or any other requirement for deletion. It is required to have 10,000 reputation do delete a question.

Comment: @acejavelin, Some gave me down votes and I am loosing reputations. Can we contact moderator to delete the same? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: @manjesh23 You gain and lose reputation, hopefully more of the former than the later which you obviously have... Getting down-votes is NOT a reason to remove a question, but perhaps it is a lesson learned to search a little first. :)

Comment: @acejavelin, thank you sir, I will make sure to check for duplicate question before asking one. thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing, you can't go beyond Z:, beyond that you would use NTFS Folder mount.

Information is detailed [here](http://ask-leo.com/26_drives_is_there_a_way_around_the_26_drive_limit_in_windows.html).

Comment: I mean what if I am looking for virtual drives? MagicISO

Comment: Windows only allows for 26 drives... period. After that you would use NTFS folder mounts or a network share shortcut. That is the way Windows is designed.

Comment: How to delete this question?